# How to replace multiple values if different from a list in ndarray Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a ndarray and I´m trying to replace its values that are not in a list given. This list will not always have the same values nor the same len size. I tried with a for loop, but it seems once the first loop is made, it saves only the firts item on the list, so when the next one is processed, it leaves everything in zero. Here is what I did:

```
arr = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [0, 3, 0, 4, 4]] 

lst = [1,2]
y,x = arr.shape
test = arr
for i in range(0, y):
    for j in range(0, x):
       value = test[i][j]
       for k in lst:
            if value != lst[k]:
                 test[i][j] = 0
            else:
                 pass
```

When I print the result, is giving me an all zero array, the result should look like this:

```
[[1 1 0 0 2]
 [1 1 0 2 2]
 [0 0 0 2 2]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Can anyone tell me please which is the most effective way of doing this?
Thank you

Comment: I understand the code, at least I think. But can you please in the future be more correct and careful and paste exactly the code that you ran? Because I got an error the first time that I ran it. E.g. add lines: ```import numpy as np``` and ```arr = np.asarray(arr)```. Furthermore, your original code contains one more error in the loop, that is `if value != lst[k]:` should be changed to `if value != k:`

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is that in line:

```
for k in lst:
```

you are asking for k=1 and k=2 in [1,2] to check if they both match
current value in array `arr` and in any case find that it is not 1 or not 2, so
they always assign value 0.

See, when value in array ( that is `test[i][j]`) equals 1 (or any number really),
it will first compare to number `1` (this happens when k = 1 in loop `for i in lst`). It will see 1 == 1, so it will pass.
Then it will in another iteration (k=2) compare to number `2`. It will see that
1 != 2, so it will run line `test[i][j] = 0` and turn value in array to zero.
So, problem is in every case, no matter which value is in array it will assign to 0. (Logically it is always true that: if not `number != 1`, than `number != 2`. ) )

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow; I replaced the line you wrote with: if value not in lst, then test[i][j] = 0, now I'm not getting all zeros, but only the number 1 group

Comment: Excellent, you did it! Well, at least I now get the desired result (array with numbers 0,1 and 2 only). I don't know why you are getting only number 1 group. Can you paste again the new changed code, just so i make sure we are on the same page?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked the code and it seems I misspelled something yesterday so now is working, here is what I did:

`for i in range(0, y):
    for j in range(0, x):
        value = test[i][j]
        if value not in lst:
            test[i][j]=0`

Comment: Yes, that is also what I meant. Well done. At the end I hope that you have read also my upper comment immediately below your question. Just to point on some room for improvement there.

Comment: Yes, I've read it, thank you so much, I'll keep that in mind